# How to view Node app on a Linux VM with private IP?

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine

I have no experience with networking so I'm lost on how to view the Node app I hosted on a Azure Linux VM with strict privacy settings. The firewall blocks inbound and outbound HTTP requests. Since my Node app creates an HTTP server to handle requests does that mean it is impossible to view the app on the VM?

I tried to access the app in this format `private-ip-address:PORT` but the page timed out. Sorry for the vague questions. I'd just like to know whether there's some way to view a Node app on a private IP. I am leaning towards yes because it's possible to view an app on `localhost` without internet access, but would appreciate further direction. Right now I am accessing the VM through SSH

Comment: This is pretty basic networking infrastructure configuration you're asking about - not sure if Azure is the right product for you, as it's heavily dependent on you knowing your way around the configurations for things like firewalls, VNETs, etc. You may want to re-visit some more fundamental networking materials before proceeding further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your VM does not have the public IP address, it just means you cannot access it from the Internet. I see you want to access the Node app via the private IP address of the VM, then the only way is to make yourself in the VNet which the VM in.

If you want to achieve it on your local machine. You can use the [VPN with P2S](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) between your local machine and the VNet which the VM in. It's a little complex and the VPN is a bit expensive.

Another way is that you can create another VM in the same subnet of the VNet with a public IP address, then you can go inside the VM. And at this time, you can access the Node app in the VM via the private IP address of the VM like `private-ip-address:PORT`.

Write at the end, when you use the Azure Cloud, I think you'd better use the public IP address instead of the private. It's a more appropriate way.

Comment: why can't i access the site on the VM with `localhost:3000` like I can do on my computer? thanks

Comment: @ILike Yes, you can, but you need first to SSH into your VM. Then there should be a public IP address for the VM.